# Deposit stimulus check electronically without signatures?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, stimulus, federal-reserve

We went through the process of moving, and now I can't find the stimulus check.

I did take pictures of the check before moving, but the check doesn't have our signatures.

Since my bank lets me deposit electronically by sending them pictures of the check, is it possible to deposit the check by sending those pictures even though it doesn't have my signature? Or are the signatures and the "For deposit only" required for the bank to deposit it?

Comment: Only your bank can answer this question.

Comment: As long as nobody complains, the bank will probably take it - only a computer looks at it. But why would you only take a picture instead of depositing it right then?